# Importing wordcloud using Jupyter Notebook (Python)

Tags: python, dll, jupyter-notebook, word-cloud

I am using jupyter Notebook(conda root). The python version I am running is 2.7

I am having a hard time getting wordcloud installed into my environment. Here's the code

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud
```

But I got this error:

```
ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-8038e19af624> in <module>()
----> 1 from wordcloud import WordCloud

C:\Users\aneeq\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\__init__.py in <module>()
----> 1 from .wordcloud import (WordCloud, STOPWORDS, random_color_func,
      2                         get_single_color_func)
      3 from .color_from_image import ImageColorGenerator
      4 
      5 __all__ = ['WordCloud', 'STOPWORDS', 'random_color_func',

C:\Users\aneeq\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\wordcloud\wordcloud.py in <module>()
     17 from operator import itemgetter
     18 
---> 19 from PIL import Image
     20 from PIL import ImageColor
     21 from PIL import ImageDraw

C:\Users\aneeq\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>()
     56     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     57     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 58     from . import _imaging as core
     59     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
     60         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "

**ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.**
```

Can anyone explain what is this error?
I need to use world cloud for my homework assignment

Comment: Did you install your dependencies for your Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Not sure what you meant.  Wordcloud was working on juptyer noteebook about few days ago. But then I ran the code today, I got this errror. @abdullahselek

Comment: It seems your dependencies (worcloud, PIL) are missing. Try to install them before you run your scripts on Jupyter. You can install with wordcloud with `!pip install wordcloud`.

Comment: @abdullahselek, I tried to install wordcloud with command but it gives me this: 

"You are using pip version 9.0.2, however version 9.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command."

Comment: Ok first update your pip with `python -m pip install --upgrade pip` and then install your dependencies.

Comment: Did that,  But still not working, still gives me the "DLL " error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have problem with part of python `Pillow` module: with a library, that builds from `_imaging.c`. Try to reinstall python `Pillow` module from `.exe` package, not with `pip`.

Comment: @miksysn.
How do I install pillow module from .exe package?
is that thing I have to download from the website?

Comment: @AzizBokhari yes, you can find packages here https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pillow/2.7.0

Comment: after downloading the file, where do I need save the file in?

Comment: @AzizBokhari download `.exe` for your version of python, and execute it

Comment: I did that, the code is working now . Thanks for you help.